# How to pass degree Celsius as symbol to YAxis title

Tags: canvasjs

How can I pass degree Celcius symbol for yAxis
I have tried all kinds 
1. °
2. U+00B0 - unicode
3.  ° - html code
but all of them get printed as given and do not print the degree symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use suffix property to add [suffix](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/suffix/) in axis labels to do this.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    axisY: {
        suffix: " °C"
    },
    data: [{        
        type: "spline",
        yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
        dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,25), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,26), y: 29 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,27), y: 29 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,28), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,29), y: 30 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,30), y: 29 }
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```